# Listview not displaying data but it shows in logcat

Tags: android, json, listview

Actually i was trying JSON parsing example and the data which is parsed but not displaying in the listview.**In the logcat the data is coming ,but it is not displaying in list.**
I was running using an emulator.   I am not able to find the mistake.Can anyone help?

Code below shows the custom list adapter.

```
 public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    Context context;

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list,
            Context context) {
        Log.i("ListAdapter", "ListAdapter");
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("ListAdapter", "getView");
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        }
        HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        TextView trank = null,tcountry = null,tpopulation = null;
        ImageView image;

            trank = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rank);
            tcountry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country);
            tpopulation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.population);
            image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            hashmap = list.get(position);
            Log.i("list", ""+list.get(position) + "hashmp " + hashmap + hashmap.get("rank"));
        String rank = hashmap.get("rank").toString();
        String country = hashmap.get("country").toString();
        String population = hashmap.get("population").toString();
        String image_url = hashmap.get("flag");
            Log.i("ListAdapter", ""+rank + " "+ country + " " +population );

        trank.setText(rank);
        tcountry.setText(country);
        tpopulation.setText(population);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView webpage,trank,tcountry,tpopulation;
ListView lv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
String RANK = "rank";
String COUNTRY = "country";
String POPULATION = "population";
String FLAG = "flag";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    trank = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rank);
    tcountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.country);
    tpopulation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.population);
    webpage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.webpage);
    webpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String data = getDataFromWebPage();
            list = parseDataFromWeb(data);
            ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(list, getApplicationContext());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }



    });
}
```

custom list layout file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout         
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/rank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rank"
        />
      <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="country"
        />
        <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:text="population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
          <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**I got solution, actually problem was with this layout file.When i removed the inner LinearLayout problem is solved.**

[image: Previously it was displayed like this]
Previously it was displayed like this after pressing the textview

**But still i dont know why this layout file with inner LinearLayout doesnt work.**

Comment: Can you show the code where you are managing your collection? After the collection was updated, did you call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter?

Comment: Just change your custom class name and then see !!

Comment: Are you inflating list row layout or listview layout in adapter ?

Comment: oops i got it.actually problem was with my layout file..

Comment: The inner layout was `match_parent` which takes up all horizontal space, leaving no room for the flag image view.

Comment: @laalto but not only flagimage was missing but others also.i put a screenshot of it

Comment: `match_parent` height for a listview item is useless, either specify an explicit size or make it `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with the custom list layout.Because of the inner linear layout data was not displaying.After removing the inner layout ,it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should return position in getItem() method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}
```

you have to change:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
```

Comment: Piyush just see him name of custom class : Same as ListAdapter.

Comment: So new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list); and new ListAdapter(list, getApplicationContext()); both are different for him

Answer (score 1):

Make change in your code here :

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
          ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter( MainActivity.this,list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```